# RangeExpression issue for Key of Dictionary even the Key is Hashable

Tags: swift

I am getting a error from Xcode like this `Subscript 'subscript(_:)' requires that 'T' conform to 'RangeExpression'` when I use this code below:

```
func test<T>(key: T) where T: Hashable {

    let dic: Dictionary<String, String> = ["1": "a"]
    
    if let unwrappedValue = dic[key] {
        print(unwrappedValue)
    }
 
}
```

I really do not see any reason that Xcode should complain! Because the Apple documentation says:

> @frozen public struct Dictionary<Key, Value> where Key : Hashable { ...

So as you can see in my code, I gave what should be done! So why am I receiving this error?!

Comment: The error message is misleading. Your dictionary expects a *string* as a key, not just any hashable type. – What would you expect as a result if `T` is (for example) an integer type? In other words: What should `test(key: 123)` print?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
func test(key: String) {

    let dic: Dictionary<String, String> = ["1": "a"]
    
    if let unwrappedValue = dic[key] {
        print(unwrappedValue)
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message isn't great, but the issue is that `T` isn't related to the `Key` type of your `dic` (which is always `String`).

Your function is generic over any unbounded `T`, which allows a caller to pass non-`String` values to `key`, which wouldn't be compatible with your `dic`.

You either need to make your dictionary generic, or your function non-generic.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with hash values, it's more fundamental then that. `dic` is a dictionary that's keyed by strings (i.e. the value for its `Key` generic type param is `String`), but `key` can be any type (including `String`, but also including non-Strings). For example, would allow a caller to `test(key: 123)`. `123` clearly not a string, and it would be illegal to attempt to subscript `dic` with it.